# Pesquisa de CEP em PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, cep

O que está faltando para esse código trazer o resultado do CEP ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<! -- Trazer Resultados CEP, Rua, Bairro e Estado -->

<html lang="pt-br"> <!-- Declaração do Idioma  -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> MEU CEP </title>
    <label> Insira o CEP: </label>
    <input type="text" name="cep"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> <br />
    <label>Rua:
        <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
        <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
        <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />

    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['cep'])) {

        $cep = $_POST['cep'];

        $address = (get_address($cp));

        echo "<br><br>CEP Informado: $cep<br>";
        echo "Rua: $addres->logradoro<br>";
        echo "Bairro: $address->bairro<br>";
        echo "Estado: $adress->uf<br>";
    }

    function get_address($cep) {


        $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cep);
        $url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws$cep/xml/";

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        return $xml;
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Fiz uma nova versão com correções e inseri a classe Address , porém ainda não está retornando a Rua, Bairro e Estado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<! -- Trazer Resultados CEP, Rua, Bairro e Estado -->

<html lang="pt-br"> <!-- Declaração do Idioma  -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> MEU CEP </title>
    <label> Insira o CEP: </label>
    <input type="text" name="cep"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> <br />
    <label>Rua:
        <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
        <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
        <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />

    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['cep'])) {

        $cep = $_POST['cep'];

        $address = (get_address($cep));

        echo "<br><br>CEP Informado: $cep <br>";
        echo "Rua: $addres->logradoro<br>";
        echo "Bairro: $address->bairro<br>";
        echo "Estado: $address->uf<br>";
    }

    class Address {

        public $bairro;
        public $logradouro;
        public $uf;

        function get_address($cep) {


            $url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" . $cep . "/xml";
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            $this->bairro = $xml->bairro;
            $this->logradouro = $xml->logradouro;
            $this->uf = $xml->uf;
        }

    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seja bem-vinda Raquel Gomes, caso alguma resposta resolva seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Faça um tour https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

**Seu código tem vários erros de digitação.**

> não é $cp

```
$address = (get_address($cp));
```

> e sim $cep

```
$address = (get_address($cep));
```

> não é $addres nem $adress

```
echo "Rua: $addres->logradoro<br>";
echo "Estado: $adress->uf<br>";
```

> e sim $address

```
echo "Rua: $address->logradoro<br>";
echo "Estado: $address->uf<br>";
```

> Não é logradoro

```
echo "Rua: $address->logradoro<br>";
```

> e sim logradouro

```
echo "Rua: $address->logradouro<br>";
```

O endereço `http://viacep.com.br/ws$cep/xml/` está errado,

o correto é `http://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/xml/`

Onde está a tag `<form>...</form>` do seu formulário?

**Use esse código que vai dar certo:**

```
<?php
function get_endereco($cep){
  // formatar o cep removendo caracteres nao numericos
  $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cep);
  $url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/xml/";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
  return $xml;
}
?>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<h1>Pesquisar Endereço</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="cep">
  <button type="submit">Pesquisar Endere&ccedil;o</button>
</form>


<?php if($_POST['cep']){ ?>
<h2>Resultado da Pesquisa</h2>
<p>
  <?php $endereco = get_endereco($_POST['cep']); ?>
  <b>CEP: </b> <?php echo $endereco->cep; ?><br>
  <b>Logradouro: </b> <?php echo $endereco->logradouro; ?><br>
  <b>Bairro: </b> <?php echo $endereco->bairro; ?><br>
  <b>Localidade: </b> <?php echo $endereco->localidade; ?><br>
  <b>UF: </b> <?php echo $endereco->uf; ?><br>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

### OU SE PREFERIR USAR O SEU CORRIGIDO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<! -- Trazer Resultados CEP, Rua, Bairro e Estado -->

<html lang="pt-br"> <!-- Declaração do Idioma  -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> MEU CEP </title>
        
<form action="" method="post">        
    <label> Insira o CEP: </label>
    <input type="text" name="cep"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> <br />
    <label>Rua:
        <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
        <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
        <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
</form>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['cep'])) {

        $cep = $_POST['cep'];

        $address = (get_address($cep));

        echo "<br><br>CEP Informado: $cep<br>";
        echo "Rua: $address->logradouro<br>";
        echo "Bairro: $address->bairro<br>";
        echo "Estado: $address->uf<br>";
    }

    function get_address($cep) {


        $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cep);
        $url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/xml/";

        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        return $xml;
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada !

Answer (score -2):

falta apenas incluir a barra antes do número do cep, a sintaxe é:
http://viacep.com.br/ws/NUMERO_DO_CEP/xml/

```
$url = 'http://viacep.com.br/ws/'.$cep.'/xml/';
```

Comment: Realizei a modificação e também modifiquei  o trecho echo "Estado: $address->uf<br>";  Será que tem haver com como o php mostra as informações ?